# How to store result of a command in a variable in bat script

Tags: batch-file

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('netstat -ano | findstr 7001') do SET   myVar=%%A 
echo %myVar%
```

Command says that it does not recognize `|` before `findstr`, can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set portnumber=?

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,* delims= " %%a in ('netstat -ano') do call :handleline %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e

goto :eof

:handleLine
call :portcheck %1 %2 %2 %4 %5

rem you can have your check here
rem if %portnumber%==7001 do whatever
echo pid %4 uses port %portnumber%

goto :eof

:portcheck
set prot=%1
set ipandport=%2
set pid=%4

set pn1=%ipandport:~-1%
set pn2=%ipandport:~-2%
set pn3=%ipandport:~-3%
set pn4=%ipandport:~-4%
set pn5=%ipandport:~-5%

if !%pn2:~0,1%!==!:! set portnumber=%pn1% & goto :bailout
if !%pn3:~0,1%!==!:! set portnumber=%pn2% & goto :bailout
if !%pn4:~0,1%!==!:! set portnumber=%pn3% & goto :bailout
if !%pn5:~0,1%!==!:! set portnumber=%pn4% & goto :bailout
set portnumber=%pn5%
:bailout

goto :eof
```

Comment: hi actually  i wanted to get the pid by comparing the port number in the result which i get after doing

`netstat -ano | find 7001`

This code returned 

`C:\Users\sahil.makhija>netstat -ano | findstr 7001`
  
`TCP    0.0.0.0:7001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING  5148`

`TCP    [::]:7001              [::]:0                 LISTENING  5148`

so i had to make some changes in your code which helped me out.
This is the new code 

`FOR /F "tokens=1,2,5* delims= " %%a in ('netstat -ano') do if %%b==0.0.0.0:7001 set myvar=%%c
echo %myvar%
pause`

this stored my PID into myvar.

Answer (score 2):

Special characters like `|` must either be escaped or quoted when within IN() clause. Note that the TOKENS=1 option is not needed - it is the default.

You can use either

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr 7001') do set myVar=%%A
```

or

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"netstat -ano | findstr 7001"') do set myVar=%%A
```

Comment: Thanks @dbenham 
i modified my code accordingly and got my ans

this is the code

`for /f " tokens=1,2* delims=" %%a in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr 7001') do set myVar=%%a
echo %myvar:~-4%
pause`