# Storing command results in a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I need to search a remote directory (psexec), then store the result in a variable.

I have a directory that is filled with many other folders each containing some files I need to execute. Each computer on the network has the files I need are in different directories.

For example, I would search (using psexec) with

```
dir *Google_Chrome_49_0_2623_112_X64_EN_R01* /s
```

And I would get the result

```
 Volume in drive C is OSDISK
 Volume Serial Number is C8AD-F658

 Directory of C:\Windows\ccmcache\2a

12/04/2016  01:52 PM               458 Google_Chrome_49_0_2623_112_X64_EN_R01.cab
14/04/2016  05:26 PM            69,632 Google_Chrome_49_0_2623_112_X64_EN_R01.mst
               2 File(s)         70,090 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)         70,090 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   4,726,218,752 bytes free
```

Now I need the same batch file to cd into the directory 2a and execute a script inside.

Is there any way to store '2a' in a variable so I can cd into it?

Currently I am doing this in 2 steps, where the batch will show me the search results, then prompt for the directory:

```
psexec \\%PCNAME% cmd /c (cd ..\ccmcache ^& dir *Google_Chrome_49_0_2623_112_X64_EN_R01* /s)

SET DIRECTORY=%1
SET /P DIRECTORY=Enter Directory:
```

Problem is, I need this to be fully automated. How can I do this?

Note: I've looked at several other threads, and none of the answers seem to help me. Seemingly the results from psexec don't flow back to the local interface.
I've tried:

```
for /f %%a in (psexec \\%PCNAME% cmd /c (cd ..\ccmcache ^& dir *Google_Chrome_49_0_2623_112* /s ^| FIND "Directory of C:\Windows\ccmcache\") DO (
 SET v=%%a
)
```

to try to set the entire result line to a var, but when I check the var, it's empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store result of a command in a variable in bat script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019274/how-to-store-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-bat-script)

Comment: Have checked several threads (including linked one) and they don't help. Edited question with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that you can map to a network share with pushd and run the search there instead of dealing with psexec until you need it.

So my code now looks like:

```
pushd \\%PCNAME%\C$\Windows\ccmcache

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir *Google_Chrome_49_0_2623_112* /s ^| FIND "Directory"') DO (
 set v=%%a
 for /f "tokens=4 delims=\" %%m in ('echo !v!') do (set x=%%m)
)
popd
```

Where %x% is now the directory I'm searching for.

Comment: Why don't you primarily use `dir /S/B` and parse with for without delims to have `%%~dpa` for the folder and `%%~nxa` for name.ext ?